# Reading Json data from Athena

Tags: amazon-athena

i have created a table by mapping the json data, unfortunately i am not able to read the nested array within the json.

````
{
"total":10,
"count":100,
"values":{
        "source":[{"sourceid":"10001","source":"ABC"},
                  {"sourceid":"10002","source":"XYZ"}
         ]}
}

```athena table
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE source_master_data(
    total bigint,
    count bigint,
    values struct<source: array<struct<sourceid: string>>>
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
LOCATION 's3://sourcemaster/'


I am trying to read the sourceid and source but no luck.. can anyone help me out

select t1.source.sourceid
from source_master_data
cross join UNNEST(source_master_data.Values) AS t1
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `unnest` need to be placed on the array type. In your query, you are trying to unnest the struct which is not possible in Athena.

The second issue is the use of `values` without quotes. This also fails, because `values` is a reserved word in  Athena.

The overall query would look something like this.

```
select t1.source.sourceid
from source_master_data
cross join UNNEST(source_master_data."values".source) AS t1 (source)
```